# problem with tensorflow instalation on nvidia jetson tx2

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, ubuntu, nvidia

I'm trying to install tensorflow on jetson tx2.

I have:

- ubuntu 18.04
- jetpack 4.5 (Version: 4.5-b129)
- python 3.6.9
- pip 21.3.1

I did step by step instruction provided by nvidia (https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/install-tf-jetson-platform/index.html), but in the last step when i run command

`$ sudo pip3 install --extra-index-url http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/jp/45 tensorflow`

It returns:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow`

Note:
I changed https to http to avoid SSL error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I find out ;)

My solution was to download .whl package with wget command:

```
sudo wget --trusted-host https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/jp/v45/tensorflow/tensorflow-2.5.0+nv21.6-cp36-cp36m-linux_aarch64.whl
```

and then directly install this package by pip3

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related with the pip3 version.

Steps that I followed:

1. Downgrade pip3

   sudo pip3 install -U pip==20.2.4
2. Reinstall tensorflow

   sudo pip3 install --pre --extra-index-url https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/jp/v45 tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0+nv19.12

If it didnt solve the issue please check the python version.

Jetson TX2 initially comes with Python 3.6 preinstalled, which is required for various system components and libraries. However, you can install Python 3.8 will be as a separate executable named python3.8. The system Python version (python3) will still remain as the default Python interpreter.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.8
python3.8 --version
```

Now install tensorflow:

```
pip3.8 install tensorflow
```